# How to pythonically pass numpy.array to method of objects in numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, iteration

I have a 2d numpy array `txtStrs` containing strings which I write as text onto a matplotlib figure axis `ax` using e.g.

```
ax.text( posX, posY, txtStrs[0,0] )
```

Later on, I want to **update** these texts (same positions, colors, etc.) without redrawing the whole figure. I therefore saved the text objects to another numpy array.

When I now want to update the texts I used two for loops

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    siz = 20

    txtStrs = np.empty( (siz, siz), dtype = str )
    txtObjs = np.empty( (siz, siz), dtype = object )

    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.gca()
    for x in range(siz):
        for y in range(siz)):
            txtObjs[x,y] = ax.text( x, y, "" )

    #Fill txtStrs with some string values

    for x in range(siz):
        for y in range(siz)):
            txtObjs[x,y].set_text( txtStrs[x,y] )
```

The last for-loop seems unnecessary and not really pythonic to me. If I didn't need to call the `set_text` method, I could use numpy's intrinsic comprehensions for the update.

My question is: Is there another way to pass the `txtStrs` to the `txtObjs`, e.g. using vectorize, list-comprehension or anything else?

Comment: Why are you using `numpy.ndarray` objects at all?

Comment: Careful with the `dtype=str`, that's equivalent to `U1`, a single character string!

Comment: When you create a `text` (with `ax.text`), `ax` appends it to its own `.texts` list.  I'm not recommending using that directly, but it's evidence that you shouldn't shy away from keeping your own `text` objects (and strings) in lists (or lists of lists).

Comment: @hpaulj You mean list of lists instead of 2d array? I was hoping for some smart compiled numpy functionality... (I used `dtype=str` only here to shorten the snippet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops are Pythonic!

And using the `set_text` method of the `matplotlib.text` object is also valid Python.  That's how we work with objects - use their methods.

With `numpy` we try to avoid loops, but that is only a significant time saver if the array contains numeric (or string) dtypes.  Then it can do the iteration in compiled code using the provided array methods.  Your `txtObjs` array is object dtype, and most operations on such an array involve a Python level iteration, even if it is hidden.  Like a list an object array contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.  It has to reference each object and use its own methods.

Iteration on object arrays is a bit slower than iteration on lists, though the multidimensional nature of arrays can make the iteration prettier.

List comprehension is a neat way of writing a for loop - if you are returning a new list.  It doesn't apply to in-place modifications.  Same goes for some numpy functions that 'vectorize' (hide) iteration.

If `txtObjs` and `txtStrs` are lists of the same size, then

```
for a, b in zip(txtObjs, txtStrs):
    a.set_text(b)
```

should update all the `text` objects.

For the 2d arrays:

```
for a, b in zip(txtObjs.ravel(), txtStrs.ravel()):
```

should also work.  The 2d shape of these arrays gets in the way of simply transfering values, though it may be convenient with setting the initial coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that will reduce those two loops to only one, but I don't really think that there is an "apply", "forEach" or anything like that.

```
for (x, y), text_obj in np.ndenumerate(txtObjs):
    text_obj.set_text(txtStrs[x, y])
```

This uses [ndenumerate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html#numpy.ndenumerate), which is a neat way of iterating through a n-dimensional numpy array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `ndenumerate`, I wasn't aware of that and I like the code readability. In my use case I take care of the two arrays being exactly one-to-one structured which is why I switched to the ravel-and-zip solution.